# Summon Dependency injenction and calling an method/function inside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, nodemailer

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am unsure how to do the following. I have a module to send emails, and the Config is injected into the module using summon.js dependency injection, but I need to use the sendMail method and pass it the parameter mailOptions. Here is the code example:

```
'use strict';

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs');



module.exports = function(Configs) {

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: Configs.email.host,
        port: Configs.email.port,
        auth: {
            user: Configs.email.user,
            pass: Configs.email.pass
        }
    });

    this.sendMail = function(mailOptions) {
        mailOptions.to = Configs.mockEmail || mailOptions.to
        mailOptions.from = Configs.email.user
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (mailOptions.template) {
                ejs.renderFile('/../templates/' + mailOptions.template + 
                             '.ejs', mailOptions.data, null, (err, html) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(html)
                })
                return
            }
            resolve()
        }).then(html => {
            mailOptions.html = html || mailOptions.html
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                // send mail with defined transport object
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                    if (error) {
                        return reject(error)
                    }
                    resolve(info)
                })
            })
        })
    }

    return this
}
```

Then, I want to make use of this module:

```
const EmailUtil = require('email')

async function foo() {
   // Do something async with await.

   const mailOptions = {...}
   EmailUtils.sendMail(mailOption);
}
```

However, it gives me the error: 
`TypeError: EmailUtils.sendMail is not a function`

Note: I can remove the module.export = function(Configs) but them that will not be good since i would need to hard code the path of my config file and I have multiple configuration files for each environment. Then, I want to be able to keep Summon.js dependency injection while calling sendMail from another module. Thanks

Any ideas??
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're exporting a function you need to actually call it after requiring the module:

```
const EmailUtil = require('email')

async function foo() {
   // Do something async with await.

   const mailOptions = {...}
   EmailUtil().sendMail(mailOption);
}
```

Comment: That worked partially. I am able to get the Configs, but i have to pass it as a paramerter such as. ```EmailUtils(Configs).sendMail(mailOptions)```. But now it gives Cannot set property sendMail of undefined.

Comment: In you code sample you require the module as `const EmailUtil = require('email')` ´, so you need to call it like this: `EmailUtil(Configs).sendMail(mailOption);`

Comment: Correct, and I did but it gives me the error: ```cannot set property 'sendMail of undefined```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `this` suggests that a function is supposed to be used as a constructor. There will be desired `this` object only if a function is called with `new` or bound to some context.

There is a convention in JavaScript to use pascal-cased names for constructors, so they could be identified unambiguously in the code.

For given `EmailUtil`, it should be:

```
const EmailUtil = require('email');
const emailUtil = new EmailUtil(config);
...
emailUtil.sendMail(mailOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer this by including EmailUtils in the depend.json file which takes care of defining the dependencies for summonjs. In this way, I was able to pass the Configs to EmailUtils and call sendMail in such way.

`EmailUtils.sendMail(mailOptions);`

There was no need to use the keyword new, which is a great answer. I was not aware a module could be instantiated in this way.